# Annotate generated web service client Java interface

Tags: java, annotations, cxf, wsdl2java, annox

While generating an Apache CXF web service client with Maven, is there a way to add a custom annotation on a Service Endpoint Interface (SEI) class through the JAX-WS bindings file?

So far, it seems to me that things like [Annox](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin) are restricted to datatypes from the schema and JAXB bindings. I tried setting the `annox` on the JAX-WS binding for the `portType` element of the WSDL, but it did not pick it up.

Thank you.